# How to prevent one specific app from reopening, or delay it

Tags: macos, applications, startup

I'm on Catalina 10.15.7, this reopening feature is awesome and really useful but some of my apps when opened by it since it's too early when this happens, they won't function property I have to close them and open them again, is there any ways that I can delay or even exclude an app from the reopening windows feature?

[image]

The picture is just for showing you what I'm talking about but I do the restart not log out.

Comment: Which app is causing issues?

Comment: @nohillside It's called Intellij, when it boots using this it doesn't recognize its license, I have to close it and reopen it then it does, I guess by the time this happens its license agent hasn't still been booted or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's done.

1. We go to `~/Library/Saved Application State/` we find the folder for our app mine is `com.jetbrains.intellij.savedState`
2. Open the folder, remove everything inside.
3. Go back to `~/Library/Saved Application State/`
4. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>  on the folder name (mine is `com.jetbrains.intellij.savedState`) now check the *locked*

[image]

Now your app can't fill the folder again, causing it to be removed from the restore of the windows, all other apps will still be restored.